# I cannot connect Java to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have to classes that connect to the same Database in MySQL, the first class I've connected was okay, but the second class that connect to the same table is show an error message like this

> Can not issue data manipulation statements with `executeQuery()`.

What's wrong?
This is the first class code which is have no error:

```
    if(evt.getKeyChar()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER ){
            try {
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from TbSignUp where username='"+txt1.getText()+"' and userpassword='"+txt2.getText()+"'");
            if(rs.next()){
            FrmMain fm = new FrmMain();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to "+txt1.getText()+"","Information Message",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            fm.setVisible(true);
            this.setVisible(false);
            }
            else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Failed","Error Meassage",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            txt1.setText("");
            txt2.setText("");
            txt1.requestFocus();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FrmLogin.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        }
```

This is the second class:

```
    if(evt.getKeyChar()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER ){

        if(txt6.getText().equals(txt7.getText())){
    try {

    stmt.executeQuery("Insert into TbSignUp(FirstName,LastName,Username,Userpassword) values('"+txt3.getText()+"','"+txt4.getText()+"','"+txt5.getText()+"','"+txt7.getText()+"')");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Create Successfully", "Congratulation Meassage",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            FrmLogin fl = new FrmLogin();
            fl.setVisible(true);
            this.setVisible(false);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FrmSignUp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password Not Match", "Error Message",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        }
```

Comment: where is your `code` ?

Comment: Ya, debugging code is pretty hard when we have no code.

Comment: That error message is exceedingly clear. You can use executeQuery() only for queries. If you want to do something that changes the data in the database, and you need to call a different method on the statement class -- for example, there is an executeUpdate() method you can look into.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: You should use a PreparedStatement, rather than concatenating strings, and you shouldn't execute blocking operations on the event thread.

Answer (score 2):

`Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().`

You can only perform `select` statement in `executeQuery()` to update database you should use `executeUpdate()`

```
stmt.executeUpdate("Insert into TbSignUp(FirstName,LastName,Username,Userpassword) values('"+txt3.getText()+"','"+txt4.getText()+"','"+txt5.getText()+"','"+txt7.getText()+"')");
```

And You should use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) as suggested by `@EJP`